# Pass two arrays of strings and count the occur y array in x array in Java

Tags: java, arrays, string, count

I created a Java method which when passed two arrays of strings x and y, counts the number of times each string occurring in y occurs in x and prints the results in the order the strings appear in y. For example, look at the main function, it should output as ab: 2, dc: 1, ef: 0. My code didn't work as it outputs ab: 1, ab: 2, dc: 3.

```
public class stringOccurInArray {
    public static void stringOccurInY(String[] x, String[] y) {
        int count = 0;
        for(int i=0; i<x.length; i++)  {
            for(int j=0; j<y.length; j++) {
                if(y[j].contains(x[i])) {
                    count++;
                    System.out.println(y[j] + ": " + count);
                }
            }
        }
        count = 0; // reset the count
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String[] a = {"ab", "cd", "ab", "dc", "cd"};
        String[] b = {"ab", "dc", "ef"};

        stringOccurInY(a, b);
    }
}
```

Comment: Why are you using `contains()` instead of `equals()`?

Comment: Also, try using an `ArrayList` instead of traditional arrays.

Comment: Before putting this question did you even try to debug your code once?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are several things to mention. It's easier to rewrite your code like this:

```
public static void stringOccurInY(String[] x, String[] y) {
    int count = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < y.length; i++) {          
        for (int j = 0; j < x.length; j++) {
            if (y[i].contains(x[j])) {
                count++;
            }
        }
        System.out.println(y[i] + ": " + count);
        count = 0; // reset the count
    }
}
```

you should iterate over y in the first place.

Also you could replace iterating via foreach loop.

```
for (String aY : y) {
    int count = 0;
    for (String aX : x) {
        if (aY.contains(aX)) {
            count++;
        }
    }
    System.out.println(aY + ": " + count);
    //no need to reset the count
}
```

Comment: In this case, `count` doesn't need to be reset after the for, as it is re-initialized before it

Comment: thanks, took the initialization out of the loop, though it doesn't make sense to have count variable out of the loops. it will have the last calculated count from the loop

Comment: second implementation removes the need to resetting

Answer (score 1):

Define `int j = 0` outside the loop, then move  `System.out.println(y[j] + ": " + count);` to outside the first `for` loop and reset `count` to 0 in the first line of the outer `for` loop.

BTW, why don't you use [String#equals](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#equals%28java.lang.Object%29)?

Answer (score 1):

```
public static void stringOccurInY(String[] x, String[] y) {
        int count = 0;
        for(int i=0; i<x.length; i++)  {
            for(int j=0; j<y.length; j++) {
                if(y[j].contains(x[i])) {
                    count++;
                }
            }    
            System.out.println(y[j] + ": " + count);
            count = 0; // reset the count
        }
    }
```

Comment: You should print the result outside the inner for loop.

Comment: @MarounMaroun thanks... made the mistake with the if scope and first scope

Answer (score 1):

Make the following modifications to get it to work right:

Switch `x` and `y` in the `for` loops.

Print in the outer loop to avoid repeating prints for one occurrence.

Initialize `count` inside the outer loop to avoid repeatedly initializing it.

```
public class stringOccurInArray {
    public static void stringOccurInY(String[] x, String[] y) {
        for(int i=0; i<y.length; i++)  {
            int count = 0;
            for(int j=0; j<x.length; j++) {
                if(x[j].equals(y[i])) {
                    count++;
                }
            }
            System.out.println(y[i] + ": " + count);
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String[] a = {"ab", "cd", "ab", "dc", "cd"};
        String[] b = {"ab", "dc", "ef"};

        stringOccurInY(a, b);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code should be :

```
for(int i=0; i<x.length; i++)  { 
count = 0;
for(int j=0; j<y.length; j++) {
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try below code as well. Does exactly what you want:

```
public static void stringOccurInY(String[] x, String[] y) {
        int count = 0;
        HashMap<String, Integer> map = new HashMap<String, Integer>();
        for(int i=0; i<x.length; i++)  {
            for(int j=0; j<y.length; j++) {
                if(y[j].contains(x[i])) {
                     if(map.get(y[j]) != null){
                         count = (int) map.get(y[j]);
                         count++;
                         map.put(y[j], count);
                     }else{
                         map.put(y[j], 1);
                     }

                }
            }

        }
        System.out.println(map);
    }
```